# "Missing URI template variable 'teamLeadId' for method parameter of type Long"

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot

I'm trying to get `teamLeadId` and trying to pass it in the list but it is showing as missing URI template variable! Why this is happening?

```
@GetMapping(value = "pppp/{id}" , produces =MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) 
      public List<Team>getUserById(@PathVariable("teamLeadId") Long teamLeadId){
          List<Team> team = (List<Team>) teamService.fetchTeamsByTeamLeadId(teamLeadId); 
          return team;}
```

Answer (score 2):

To solve the described problem, you should replace `pppp/{id}` with `pppp/{teamLeadId}` - the variable `id` does not occur in your function.

Comment: @B--rian It does answer the question. Although it could do with some explanation, it is an answer nonetheless.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - you are right, I chose the wrong option during Review, sorry for that. I tried to improve the answer with an edit just now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `value = "pppp/{teamLeadId}"`

It's looking for that exact variable name in the path you've defined in your GetMapping

Answer (score 1):

Because you take Path param as id.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/pppp/{id}")
```

and you try to access teamLeadId

```
@PathVariable("teamLeadId")
```

So it not able to find out. You have to use same name in this. 
Like,

```
@PathVariable("id") Long teamLeadId
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why this is happening?

There's a **mismatch** between the variable name used in the URI template of the [`@GetMapping`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/GetMapping.html) annotation (`id`) and the value indicated in the [`@PathVariable`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PathVariable.html) annotation (`teamLeadId`). Use one of the following:

```java
@GetMapping("/pppp/{id}") 
public List<Team> getUserById(@PathVariable("id") Long teamLeadId) {
    ...
}
```

```java
@GetMapping("/pppp/{teamLeadId}") 
public List<Team> getUserById(@PathVariable("teamLeadId") Long teamLeadId) {
    ...
}
```

---

Starting on Java 8, if your code is compiled with the `-parameters` compiler flag *and* if the method parameter name matches the URI variable name, then you don't need to specify the variable name in the [`@PathVariable`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PathVariable.html) annotation. For example, if the URI variable name is `id` and the method parameter name is also `id`, then you can have the following:

```java
@GetMapping("/pppp/{id}") 
public List<Team> getUserById(@PathVariable Long id) {
    ...
}
```

Refer to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates) for details.